# Passing Props Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to pass a prop from the main Vue instance  to a component. I am passing two props, the first one works but the second one does not for some reason.

## Main Instance

```
  var app7 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-7',
    template: `<div class="b">
                    <div>
                        <button class="c" v-on:click="previousDay">&lsaquo;</button>
                        <h1 >{{ this.ss }}</h1>
                        <button class="c" v-on:click="nextDay">&rsaquo;</button>
                    <div>
                    <emp-item
                    v-for="item in empList"
                    v-bind:emp="item"
                    v-bind:key="item.id">
                    v-bind:lines="lines"
                    </emps-item>
                    </div>`,
    data: function() {
    return {
    empList : l,
    lines: 0,
    day: 0
    }
// other stuff
```

## Component

```
Vue.component('emp-item', {
    props: ['emp', 'lines'],
    template: `<div class="cv">
                <h6>{{emp.first_name}} {{ lines }}</h6>
                <canvas  v-on:mousedown="mouseDown" v-on:mousemove="mouseMove" v-on:mouseup="mouseUp" :id="'cv' + emp.id" class="canvas"  width="150" height="700"></canvas>

                </div>`,
    data: function() {
        return {

            rect : {},
            drag : false,
            startTime : 0,
            cv: ''

        }
    },
    watch: {
        lines: function () {
            console.log('watch: ');
        }
    },
// methods
```

## Incase it matters HTML

```
<div id="app-7">

    <app></app>

</div>
```

Comment: You closed your `<emp-item>` tag before the binding of lines → it is just considered text. (and I mean the opening tag itself, not that you missed the closing tag)

Answer (score 1):

You close the component tag before it binds the second prop.  It should look like this:

```
var app7 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-7',
    template: `<div class="b">
                    <div>
                        <button class="c" v-on:click="previousDay">&lsaquo;</button>
                        <h1 >{{ this.ss }}</h1>
                        <button class="c" v-on:click="nextDay">&rsaquo;</button>
                    <div>
                    <emp-item
                    v-for="item in empList"
                    v-bind:emp="item"
                    v-bind:key="item.id"
                    v-bind:lines="lines">
                    </emps-item>
                    </div>`,
    data: function() {
        return {
            empList : l,
            lines: 0,
            day: 0
    }
})
```